# If print the console log, it is normal. but execution is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs

### depth

```js
<Body title="User List" subTitle="유저 목록 페이지입니다." store={this.props.store}>

<Sidebar store={this.props.store}/>
```

insert 2 depth.

### main code

```js
setSidebar = () => {
  const url = `${API_URI.SIDEBAR}?token=${this.props.store.token}`;
  console.log(url) // token is not empty
  axios.get(url).then((data: any) => {
    this.setState({activeUrls: 
      data.data.map((sidebar: any) => {
        const path = this.getSidebarPath(sidebar);
        return sidebar.allowed ?
        <li key={sidebar.key} className="nav-item">
          <Link href={path}><a href={path} className="nav-link">
            <i className={sidebar.icon}></i>
            <span>{sidebar.title}</span>
          </a></Link>
        </li> : <li></li>
      })
    });
  });
}

componentDidMount() {
  {this.setSidebar()};
}
```

this code is not empty token value.

[image: token is empty]

> GET http://localhost:8000/apis/sidebar?token= 500

If print the console log, it is normal. but execution is empty.

Comment: This code doesnt make sense, its syntax error `{this.setSidebar()}`.

Comment: And you can get error within the `then` callback, like the error states: "Error in promise". Please make reproducible example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: As noted in [ask] and other areas of the [help/on-topic], please include error meesages as text, not as images of text. Also the code you are running is asynchronous.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thank you for your comment. i got the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has 2 problems:

- You are having an 500 error, this is not related to react, check the network tag on your console and verify what is wrong with your ajax request
- You are returning XML from an async function and storing it inside the state. This is not recommended

What you should do is store the data itself on state and use t on render:

```js
render(){
return ...
       {this.state.ajaxData && ...}
}
```